# How to validate that dependencies are correctly installed on a spark slave node?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write and run a test that demonstrates that all the slaves in an AWS EMR cluster have a required dependency of a pyspark package (defined in a requirements.txt somewhere else).

```
# tests/test_basic.py

import unittest
import pyspark

class SimpleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName("testing")
        cls.sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.sc.stop()

    def test_use_scipy(self):
        test_input = [
            ' hello spark ',
            ' hello again spark spark'
        ]

        input_rdd = self.sc.parallelize(test_input)

        from operator import add

        def f(x):
            import scipy
            # an hypotetical operation that requires scipy
            return x.split()

        results = input_rdd.flatMap(f).map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(add).collect()

        self.assertEqual(set(results), {('hello', 2), ('spark', 3), ('again', 1)})
```

I am executing the code on the master as follow:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3 python3 -m unittest
```

I do not understand why this test passes: when I ssh the slave, `pip-3.4 list` does not contain `scipy`. I would expect this code to fail because the slave does not have the dependency to run.

I suspect that the job is not being executed by the slave, possibly because I am not using `spark-submit`. This is because the test fails when I uninstall `scipy` from the master node.

How do I run Python unit tests on a hypothetical staging EMR cluster?